# How to display arbitrary images of a server in Django 2.1?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.1

1. Have a web interface.
2. I can select any path of the server on the web interface.
3. Display all the images in this path to the web interface.

try:

1. I can't use these images as static resources.
2. If I take the absolute path of the image as the 'src' of the 
    tag, it will cause the image 404 error.

What should I do if I want to make this image's url correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can not, by design. Django uses [`Storage` engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/) to handle files it has access to (even files using [remote services](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

To reference static files, using the `{% static 'relative/to/static.jpg' %}` template tag, you need to use the included [staticfiles module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/).

To reference uploaded files, you can use `{{MEDIA_URL}}` as [illustrated the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url).

The reason for this approach in Django is that it protects against attempts to reference files outside the [base location](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage.location) of the Storage engine and throw a [SuspiciousOperation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation) exception.

Naturally, you can write your own Storage engine and reference files in any way you want.

And one could use any of these [packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/file-managers/) to manage them.